# Add text to a popup image only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this free HTML template https://html5up.net/ethereal

In the portfolio section, when you click on an image, the image appears bigger for a better view.

I want to add some info or some text along with the popup image but somehow cannot add it to this code

```
<a href="https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/ethereal/images/gallery/thumbs/01.jpg" class="image filtered span-3" data-position="bottom"><img src="https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/ethereal/images/gallery/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: You are going to have create some kind of a parent element that will contain the HTML that you have provided in your question along with a text element, such as a <p> tag. You could then use absolute positioning to place the text over the image.

Comment: So you are saying to wrap that element with a <p> tag ? I don't want to place the text over the image, but rather near it, like an image with infos.

Comment: No, you will need a parent element, like a <div> tag for example. Then position your image and text elements however you wish.

Comment: When I try an parent element like you said, the image completely disappears. If you look at the code I provided, the image that is showing is in an <a> tag, not an <img> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on your comments: There are many approaches to toggling hidden content, below you will find a basic example. We are hiding the element with the class "hidden" and wiring up an event listener on the default image. Once the default image is clicked on it will fire a function that gets the parent element and applies a new class. In our CSS we are then hiding the default image and showing the previously hidden content. This is a rough example and by expanding on the styling you can do all sorts of things such as fading the hidden content in by setting a transition on the element's opacity or sliding the hidden content into view by transitioning the transform properties as a couple of examples.

```js
var target = document.querySelector(".parent .default");

target.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
  parent.classList.add("show-hidden");
});
```

```css
.parent {
  padding: 15px;
 }
 
 .parent p {
   color: black;
   font-size: 16px;
 }
 
 .hidden {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .parent.show-hidden .hidden {
  display: block
 }
 
 .parent.show-hidden .default {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img class="default" src="https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/ethereal/images/gallery/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="hidden">
        <img src="https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/ethereal/images/gallery/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" />
        <p>I am the text element</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but I think you inverted it ? What I was trying to say is that once you clicked on the image, the image with the text will show. Not the other way.

Comment: You want to click an image and have a different image show?

Comment: No, I want to click the image and show a whole div/page with informations about that image, instead of showing the same image.

Comment: Then set the href of the <a> tag to the URL of the page you want to show. Or if you want to display an element on the same page without navigating to a completely different page then remove the <a> tag and instead create a new element that contains the content that you want to show, hide it via CSS, place a click listener on the current image that will toggle a CSS class on the hidden element to show it once the class is applied.

Comment: The second option seems reasonable as I want to stay in the same page. Do you have some code for that listener thing ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please accept the answer if this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. Even though I don't know but I'm starting to think that I have some interference with some other javascript code. If I remove the <a> tag like you did, the modal doesn't work anymore at all. I have only a simple image that I can click.